# MySQL deadlock for queries using primary key for UPDATE with equality condition on WHERE. Why?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I have the following problem. MySQL SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS tells me, that the following two queries caused deadlock:

- `UPDATE xf_user SET conversations_unread = '1' WHERE (user_id = 209495)`
- `UPDATE xf_user SET last_activity = '1431370106' WHERE (user_id = 417599)`

How can this be? Both are UPDATE queries and both has a single primary key equality condition in WHERE. There is no constrains on a table.

SHOW CREATE TABLE xf_user:

```
xf_user CREATE TABLE `xf_user` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('','male','female') NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Leave empty for ''unspecified''',
  `custom_title` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `style_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '0 = use system default',
  `timezone` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Example: ''Europe/London''',
  `visible` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Show browsing activity to others',
  `user_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `secondary_group_ids` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  `display_style_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User group ID that provides user styling',
  `permission_combination_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `conversations_unread` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `register_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trophy_points` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `alerts_unread` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avatar_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avatar_width` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avatar_height` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gravatar` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'If specified, this is an email address corresponding to the user''s ''Gravatar''',
  `user_state` enum('valid','email_confirm','email_confirm_edit','moderated','email_bounce') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'valid',
  `is_moderator` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_admin` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_banned` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `like_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `warning_points` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `members_page` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_last_login` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_current_login` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_profile_validated` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_staff` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_consultant` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fh_modified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activity_visible` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `user_state` (`user_state`),
  KEY `last_activity` (`last_activity`),
  KEY `members_page` (`members_page`),
  KEY `message_count` (`message_count`),
  KEY `trophy_points` (`trophy_points`),
  KEY `like_count` (`like_count`),
  KEY `register_date` (`register_date`),
  KEY `staff_username` (`is_staff`,`username`),
  KEY `is_moderator` (`is_moderator`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1605433 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS excerpt:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2015-05-11 22:10:14 7f4240cd0700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3310570290, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 21 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 24 row lock(s), undo log entries 31
MySQL thread id 17046111, OS thread handle 0x7f42415f0700, query id 663191550 192.168.100.19 xxxxxx updating
UPDATE `xf_user` SET `conversations_unread` = '1' WHERE (user_id = 209495)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 708 page no 290 n bits 176 index `PRIMARY` of table `xxxxxx`.`xf_user` trx id 3310570290 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 3310570063, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
297 lock struct(s), heap size 30248, 986 row lock(s), undo log entries 985
MySQL thread id 17046068, OS thread handle 0x7f4240cd0700, query id 663193617 192.168.100.19 xxxxxx updating
UPDATE `xf_user` SET `last_activity` = '1431370106' WHERE (user_id = 417599)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 708 page no 290 n bits 176 index `PRIMARY` of table `xxxxxx`.`xf_user` trx id 3310570063 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 708 page no 1037 n bits 176 index `PRIMARY` of table `xxxxxx`.`xf_user` trx id 3310570063 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.15-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Both queries EXPLAINed into:

`1   SIMPLE  xf_user range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   NULL    1   Using where`

I cannot post here an entire transaction since this is not my code, that causes deadlock, but of XenForo forum engine with one thousand different addons installed. I will try to make some dumping later.

Transaction isolation level is `READ COMMITTED`.

Comment: post the output of with EXPLAIN both the queries

Comment: EXPLAIN  results shows USING WHERE or not ?

Comment: Show us the entire transactions, not just the queries that got caught.  That is, let's see the SQL statements starting with `BEGIN`.

Comment: What is the meaning of `last_activity`?  If it is just a flag, do not index it.

Comment: I believe this problem is related to phantom reads. You can check out this article: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/

Comment: @HiteshMundra Added explains to the text. AlexeyKruchinin I have READ COMMITTED as transaction isolation level. Can phantom reads be the cause of deadlocks?

Comment: @VladislavRastrusny it can. You can see the problem in the logs: `RECORD LOCKS space id 708 page no 290 n bits 176 index \`PRIMARY\` of table` - it is an attempt to lock the gap in between the index records.

Comment: @AlexeyKruchinin But there is no gap. Isn't there? Does equality condition on primary key create any gap locks? I thought only one record is locked on such updates.

Comment: @RickJames This isn't my code (it is a XenForo forum engine) and I cannot remove it. What happens with locks when you update an index record like that?

Comment: The log shows only latest commands involved in these two transactions.Without looking at whole trnsactions it's hard to give you any advices except general ones like this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html I vote for closing your question, since there is not enough information provided to solve the problem.

Comment: Turn on the "general log".  That will let us see the entire transaction.

Comment: It should be possible to `DROP` the index, even with a 3rd party package.

Comment: @RickJames Sure, but that will slow other parts of the system. It is used in sorting user list (about 900.000 records there).

Comment: OK, never mind about `INDEX(last_activity)`.